# cs50 pset5 segmentation fault [loading text in memory using hash table]

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently working on [pset5 from cs50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/5/speller/).

My entire program compiles successfully but stops in the middle of the function called `load` when program is executed.

Below is my `load` function, and you can see the comment where it gave me a `segmentation fault` error.

If you can help me with figuring out how I should approach my error, please do let me know.
I understand that `segmentation fault` is caused when the program attempts to access a memory that does not belong to it.
However, I have allocated memory and checked whether there was enough memory to continue on the program.
I will provide comments to highlight what my code does.

```
// In another header file, I have defined 'LENGTH'
// Maximum length for a word
// (e.g., pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)
#define LENGTH 45
```

```
// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Hash table
// I have initialized the array of `node` pointer to point `NULL`
node *table[N] = {NULL};

unsigned int word_counter = 0;

bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open file, and if cannot open, return false
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // read string in the file into array of character, `word` until reaching end of the file 
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // keep track of how many word exists in the file, for later use (not in this function)
        word_counter += 1;

        // allocated memory for struct type `node`, if not enough memory found, return false 
        node *n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // assign index by hashing (hash function will not be posted in this question though.)
        unsigned int index = hash(&word[0]);
        // copy the word from file, into word field of struct type `node`
        strncpy(n->word, word, sizeof(word));

        // Access the node pointer in this index from array(table), and check is its `next` field points to NULL or not. 
        // If it is pointing to NULL, that means there is no word stored in this index of the bucket
        if (table[index]->next == NULL)    // THIS IS WHERE PROGRAM GIVES 'segmentation fault' !!!! :(
        {
            table[index]->next = n;
        }
        else
        {
            n->next = table[index];
            table[index]->next = n;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define ant initialize the hash table as:

```
node *table[N] = {NULL};
```

That means you have an array of null-pointers.

When you insert the first value in the table, then `table[index]` (for *any* valid index) will be a null pointer. That means `table[index]->next` attempt to dereference this null pointer and you will have undefined behavior.

You need to check for a null pointers first:

```
if (table[index] == NULL)
{
    n->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    n->next = table[index];
}

table[index] = n;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mind explaining why we do `table[index] = n;` instead of `table[index]->next = n;`. If we don't dereference to `next`, the head node will never be making use of its `next` field inside its struct right?

Comment: @FluffyCat But for a new entry (an unused `index`) there is no head node. And as I said, a `NULL` can't be dereferenced. By using `table[index] = n` we make `n` the new head of the list.